# z3Py Array manipulation and time efficiency

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm new to z3 and after some research I couldn't figure it out how to solve my problem.

The original code is taking a string as input and produce a pseudo random string as output. I'm trying to find out how I could produce an arbitrary string as output.

My main problem is that my z3 program is running forever. This is mainly because the original code has loops and his manipulating arrays.

To me I must use z3 array because I need to use BitVec as array index.
The original code :

```
from pwn import *
my_command = ordlist("\x41\x41\x41\x41\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")

final = ["\x00"]*50
i = 0x0
alpha = []
while i <= 0xff:
    alpha.append(i)
    i = i + 1

v2 = 0
v1 = 0
while v1 < 255:
    v3 = alpha[v1];
    v4 = (v2 + my_command[v1 % 19] + alpha[v1] & 0xFF);
    v2 = v4;
    alpha[v1] = alpha[v4];
    v1 = v1 + 1
    alpha[v4] = (v3 & 0xFF);

v5 = 0
v6 = 0;
v7 = 0;
while v5 < 10:
    v5 = v5 + 1
    v8 = alpha[(v7 + 1)];
    v7 = v7 + 1;
    v9 = alpha[(v8 + v6) & 0xFF];
    v6 = (v8 + v6) & 0xFF;
    alpha[v7] = v9;
    alpha[v6] = v8;
    final[(v5 - 1)] = alpha[((alpha[v7] + v8) & 0xFF)];
```

Transposed to :

```
from pwn import *
from z3 import *

solver = Solver()

for i in range(0, 20):
    globals()['b%i' % i] = BitVec('b%i' % i, 32)
    solver.add(globals()['b%i' % i] >= 0x0)
    solver.add(globals()['b%i' % i] <= 0xff)

i = 0x0
alpha = []
while i <= 0xff:
    alpha.append(i)
    i = i + 1

A = Array ('A', BitVecSort(32), BitVecSort(32))
for i in range(0, len(alpha)):
    # A = Store(A,i,alpha[i])
    solver.add(Select(A, i) == alpha[i])

v2 = 0
v1 = 0
while v1 < 255:
    v3 = Select(A, v1)
    v4 = (v2 + globals()['b%i' % (v1 % 19)] + Select(A,v1) & 0xFF)
    v2 = v4
    A = Store(A,v1,Select(A,v4))
    v1 = v1 + 1
    A = Store(A,v4,(v3 & 0xFF))

v5 = 0
v6 = 0
v7 = 0
v8 = 0
v9 = 0

F = [0]*50
while v5 < 10:
    v5 = v5 + 1
    v8 = Select(A,(v7+1))
    v7 = v7 + 1;
    v9 = Select(A, (( v8 + v6) & 0xFF))
    v6 = (v8 + v6) & 0xFF;
    A = Store(A,v7,v9)
    A = Store(A,v6,v8)
    F[(v5 - 1)] = Select(A,((Select(A,v7)) + v8 & 0xFF))

solver.add(F[0] == 0x41)
print solver.check()
print solver.model()
```

Is there a way to optimize my code ?
For example how would you transposed the following piece of code ?

```
while v1 < 255:
    v3 = alpha[v1];
    v4 = (v2 + my_command[v1 % 19] + alpha[v1] & 0xFF);
    v2 = v4;
    alpha[v1] = alpha[v4];
    v1 = v1 + 1
    alpha[v4] = (v3 & 0xFF);
```

Thanks,
Jackson

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to come up with a more specific question based on what you have. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should at least tell us what the problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to produce a specific string as output.
For example if the input is "AAAA", the output will be :
"05 6a 75 6e be 6f 56 93 50 23"

And I wish to control the output (F[0] == 0x41)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really anything fundamentally wrong with your model. Unfortunately, the created problem is too difficult for z3 (or any other SMT solver) to deal with. These sorts of shuffling algorithms (hashing or crypto being prime examples) are precisely designed to be one-way: Easy to compute but very hard to invert. And while your algorithm may not be crypto-grade, it still is too difficult for z3 to deal with. (The array, in particular, becomes heavily symbolically referenced, which always creates a weak spot.)

One small point: I think everything is bound to be between 0 and 255; and I see that you're clamping all output accordingly `(& 0xFF)` etc. If all arithmetic is done modulo 256, you can simply use bit-vectors of size 8. This would allow you to skip bound-checks and all the masking and furthermore would give rise to easier-to-solve problems; though I doubt it'd help with this problem.